# Plot venues from foursquare on google maps

Tags: javascript, geolocation, foursquare

I'm trying to use the Foursquare and Google API to receive my current location and from there display a range of venues, eg. restaurants in a specific radius and plot each one on the map with a custom marker.

I've been able to display my current location with the google api, but I have never used the Foursquare API and it seems a little tricky, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use either the [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) or [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint to search around the location.

As an example of using search, this [JQuery getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) call will call the search endpoint looking for venues in the 'nightspots' category within 100m of the given venue:

```
var ll = latitude + "," + longitude;        
$.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search", {
    ll: ll,
    radius: 100,
    limit: 50
    intent: "browse",
    categoryId: "4d4b7105d754a06376d81259",
    client_id: foursq_client_id,
    client_secret: foursq_client_secret,
    v: 20130420
 }).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data.response.venues, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```